# How can I run the iOS 7.1 Simulator in Xcode 6.0 Beta?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode6

I have just downloaded the developer Xcode 6 beta. and I couldn't find the settings to set the ios version.

I want to know, How can I run the iOS 7.1 Simulator in Xcode 6.0 Beta?

Comment: add simulator xcode 6

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033417/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-xcode-beta-6-ios-8

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Finally I found it

Goto Hardware -> Device -> Manage Devices (In Simulator Menu)

**or**

window -> Devices (In Xcode Menu)

From there you can set the ios version and can add new sim from there.

Comment: It's actually `Window > Devices`

Comment: Apple: Why u make it so complicated??

Comment: After downloading iOS 7.1 Simulator, in case anyone fails to find where to select 7.1 simulators, you may have to set your project's Deployment Target to 7.x. In my case the default is 8.1 so I couldn't select 7.1 simulators from the dropdown menu. Now the dropdown menu looks different with items like iPad Retina (7.1) and iPad Retina (8.1) instead of just iPad Retina, which was 8.1.

Comment: I see the list of devices (it's long -- 7.1 is there) but the choices in the simulator drop down (to the right of schema) don't reflect the list in devices. Xcode 6.3.

Comment: to `Goto Hardware -> Device -> Manage Devices (In Simulator Menu)` -> Click the `+` button at the bottom of the window on the LHS. Click up-down arrows next to iOS version -> `Download more simulators...` -> `iOS 7.1 Simulator`

Comment: The oldest possible simulator you can get in xcode 7.3.1 is iOS 8.1 as of 2016-07-28.

Answer (score 31):

You can install additional simulators through the downloads interface in xcode preferences.

[image: Xcode preferences]