# Simulators missing in Xcode6 beta6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6-beta6

I'm having weird problem in XCode6 beta6. In preferences, downloads there is only one simulator (iOS8) showing as downloaded. No other simulators available.

In addition trying to execute my project on simulator causes this same error mentioned in another question: [Unable to run app in Simulator : Xcode beta 6 iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033417/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-xcode-beta-6-ios-8)

Removing simulators and adding them back seems to crash Xcode most of the time but even if successful the simulator won't run. Rebooting the machine doesn't help either.

Anyone having similar problems and solution?

Comment: It's beta so there can always be issues, report bug to Apple and check their forum.

Comment: In the end it was third reboot that solved the case. Simulators are now working. I also filed bug report for Apple.