# FBSSystemServiceDomain code 4

Tags: ios8, xcode6

Getting the following error i haved just install iOS 8 SDK (Xcode 6).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link

[Unable to run app in Simulator : Xcode beta 6 iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033417/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-xcode-beta-6-ios-8)

Not exact error, but similar problem. I hope it helps.