# Failed to load Info.plist from bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

Cannot run app. Failed to load Info.plist from bundle error occurs.
When I `CMD+K` clean the project, it runs fine. But I have to clean the project every time I make changes and run the app.

[image]

Following is the screenshot of my podfile:
[image]

Comment: Have you found solution? I have to delete and reinstall app every time or have to do `CMD+SHIFT+ALT + K`.

Comment: @Max, Nope I couldn't find any.

Comment: I answered on similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73953023/5262417

Answer (score 81):

I had tried all suggestion and none of them work 
Then I tried to **Reset content and Setting** of simulator and it worked for me. :)

Comment: FWIW this is not in the simulated phone itself, but in the Mac menu while you're running the Simulator app, up near the Apple in the upper left portion of your screen: Click "Simulator" then "Reset Content and Settings..."

Comment: In addition to resetting the contents in simulator, also shutdown Xcode and clean the derived data folder. That worked for me.

Comment: this happened to me when I changes the BundleID of the app. Resetting content did the trick.

Comment: I try but it still doesn't resolve this issue. FYI, my build is based on React-Native.

Answer (score 30):

## Simply

Just **quit** the simulator and open it again and it should works fine

Answer (score 19):

None of the above suggestions worked for me.

Changed the  Embed setting for the complained framework to **Do Not Embed** resolved the issue. :)

[image: Build Settings]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 15):

If you're still running into this issue after trying all the reset, checkout this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61846384/1341768

In your podfile replace:

```
use_frameworks!
```

with :

```
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

Comment: only this worked to me

Answer (score 9):

1: Remove app from simulator,

2: Product > Clean ,

3: Simulator > Hardware > Reboot ,

It solved my problem.
In case it doesn't resolved, change your bundle identifier.

Comment: I did already mention in the question that I am already cleaning the project and it solves the problem temporarily i.e. I need to do it every time and it's not a permanent solution.

Comment: Check your Bundle Identifier too. I corrected it and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 8):

It was duplicated frameword when you config. Please check again in Embedded Binaries and Linked Frameworks and Libraries. With some frameworks, you don't need add in both sections, please remove one. 
It worked with me

Comment: removing from Build Phases->Embedded Frameworks worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

This error occurs due to '**RealmSwift**'. When you try to write in realm in certain directory, this error occurs, due to the conflicts in overwriting with realm.

You may want to **Reset Content & Settings** in *simulator* and also try cleaning your build folder in *Xcode* using **Cmd+Shift+Option+K**

Comment: I did already mention in the question that I am already cleaning the project and it solves the problem temporarily i.e. I need to do it every time and it's not a permanent solution. Even trying reset the content and settings of the simulator solves the problem temporally.

Comment: Well, this error occurs due to 'RealmSwift'. When you try to write in realm in certain directory, this error occurs, due to the conflicts in overwriting in realm.

Answer (score 6):

only a note hoping helps people with SPM after downloading Xcode 15.3

scenario:

- Xcode 15
- Google Mobile Ads v10.x.y via SPM

After upgrading  to Xcode 15.3 I got that weirds error.

The easy way is to remove current SPM in Xcode and re-add it at version 11.x:

[image]

Comment: I had to remove and then re-add the other packages too (essentially all of them), but it helped. Now it works again. Thank you!

Comment: I ma using GMS since Xcode 8... only pain form G-men. ;(

Comment: a side not for FB SPMs. same result in lrecnts SPMS, but the updated PSMs yesterday to satisfy Xcode 15.3... ;(

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when integrating Firebase to my project. The issue was that Xcode automatically configured project to "Embed&Sign" the libraries when I drag&drop them into "Framworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" section.

To fix that, I manually set them to "Do Not Embed".

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error in one of my projects and narrowed down a set of *exact conditions* that are able to reproduce it, thereby preventing installation to the simulator.

With Xcode 10.2.1, I was testing linking a framework. I noticed in the project navigator panel that two instances of it were present. This could have been due to my multiple attempts.

Inside the Xcode project package, I opened the file `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and confirmed that the two instances were identical. The following snippet shows an example of how this was represented.

```
/* Begin PBXFileReference section */
...
    65C8CE8522CA0D3500271FFD /* MyFrameworkForiOS.framework */ = { 
        isa = PBXFileReference; 
        lastKnownFileType = wrapper.framework; 
        name = MyFrameworkForiOS.framework; 
        path = "../my-frameworks/out/MyFrameworkForiOS.framework"; sourceTree = "<group>"; 
    };
    65C8CE8722CA0D3800271FFD /* MyFrameworkForiOS.framework */ = {
        isa = PBXFileReference; 
        lastKnownFileType = wrapper.framework; 
        name = MyFrameworkForiOS.framework; 
        path = "../my-frameworks/out/MyFrameworkForiOS.framework"; sourceTree = "<group>"; 
    };
...
/* End PBXFileReference section */
```

By **removing a duplicate reference** in the project navigator (with command-backspace), I was able to install my app to the simulator without the error.

What didn't matter was the contents of `Info.plist` in my framework as it only had an empty root dictionary. Therefore, the error message may be misleading relative to the actual cause.

Answer (score 1):

It is annoying. Temporary I remove app on simulator then rebuild project work but still waiting for a better solution
This problem likely to a problem with core data i have meet in the past.

**Update**: this solution work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24042126/5387768

Comment: But I am not using CoreData.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the app from the Simulator worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "Erase all content and settings" in help for emulator

Answer (score 1):

***swift 4,5***

i had same problem, after some analysis i just found that i removed one of framework that cause this error. adding framework again solved t for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:**
Same issue came on Xcode-11 and none of the above methods worked.

**Answer**
You need to check first the issue, where it is coming from. In my case it was due to all Pod libraries info.plist file was missing. (God knows how it got missed).

1. Comment the "pod libraries" in "pod file" and run "pod install"
2. Uncomment the "pod libraries" in "pod file" and run "pod install" again.

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have run into this a couple of times in iOS w/ React Native.  Found that a couple of extra steps helped.  What ultimately fixed was:

1: Erase all contents and settings from simulator

2: Delete node modules

3: Delete pods folder

4: Reinstall node modules

5: Reinstall pods

6: Delete top secret derived data folder for Xcode

7: Xcode -> Product -> Clean build folder

8: Close out of metro bundler

9: (optional) Buy a new Mac Book Pro

10: Run Xcode

11: Contemplate the 30 minutes you're never going to get back

Comment: 30 minutes?!! More like my entire morning :C

Answer (score 1):

For those who just updated Xcode, update the error mentioned package to the latest version may solve the issue.

For me, I got this error after updated Xcode 15.2 to 15.3. I located the error package and looked up the latest version, apply it then the error is gone.

Comment: thanks, i tried all the top answers then i saw this one is recent, the same day I started to have the issue, and you resolved it!

Answer (score 0):

If resetting the Simulator did't work. Try to change simulator like from iPhone6 to iPhone5s. Then later run in iPhone6 simulator and reset the Simulator again. It will start working.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all of the above perfectly acceptable solutions (some of which had worked for me in the past) I was running out of ideas to solve this issue - finally resorting to rebooting my MacBook which magically resolved the issue.

Sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Following the below steps solved the issue for me:

- Update the cocoapods by brew upgrade cocoapods
- Clean the build folder using cmd+shift+k
- Delete the derived data folder using cmd+shift+alt+k
- Erase content and setting of simulator
- Remove the pods completely and reinstall by rm -rf Pods\ Podfile.lock && pod install
- run the project by Xcode and the app installed successfully

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove Pods and
2. Install Pods again

is also one solution.

The reinstallation of Pods worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many options like clean build, delete derived data, erase all content and settings in the simulator, etc. But still the issue exists.

At last, I restarted the machine then I can run the app perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

use this command in terminal : `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`

then delete derived folder of Xcode

finally delete node modules and pods

reinstall node modules and pods while Xcode is closed

then start you project as normal.

Answer (score 0):

if none of the above solution works for you then you should reset xcode to default

steps:

1. defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
2. defaults delete -app xcode
3. rm -rf $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode
4. rm -rf $HOME/Library/Saved\ Application
   State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState
5. rm -rf $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.*
6. Restart macbook
7. Delete node_modules and pod folder
8. delete /Users/{YourUser}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData ( hint: click pref -> locations -> click arrow next to Drived DAta)
9. close xcode
10. install node_modules and pods
11. run project like normal.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is due to the recent update of your Xcode. The current version of Google AdMob you're using is no longer compatible with this new version of Xcode. If you're utilizing Swift Package Manager, it's probably set to version 10.x.x, which means it updates to new minor versions within the 10.x.x range but doesn't automatically switch to the latest major version, version 11.x.x.

To resolve this issue, you'll need to manually change the version from 10.x.x to 11.x.x in the Swift Package Manager settings and then resolve the package again. This should ensure compatibility with your updated version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to update all my package dependencies to their latest versions.