# Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path

Tags: ios, xcode8.2

I am using xcode 8.2.1. For the first time or just after deleting the app from the simulator it's working fine. But from the second time I got the following error!!!

[image]

I tried to solve my problem from the following links, but those also doesn't work for me.

[Failed to load Info.plist from bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327935/failed-to-load-info-plist-from-bundle)

[Unable to run app in Simulator : Xcode beta 6 iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033417/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-xcode-beta-6-ios-8/24042126#24042126)

Any other solution?

Comment: were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 13):

**First Try**

Cleaning the build folder resolved the issue for me. I hope it helps someone!

(While holding down the Alt-key: Product > Clean build folder)

**Second Try**

Launch/Relaunch the iphone simulator then go to simulator->reset contents and settings. Then,quit all the application and restart your mac.

Comment: Thanks for posting... it has been already fixed but I am not sure how as I tried lots of tricks. Hope this will help others.

Comment: Thanks! Second try worked. This seems to happen so rarely nowadays, that resetting the simulator is not the first thing I think of when Xcode starts acting funny.

Comment: In addition to resetting the contents in simulator, also shutdown Xcode and clean the derived data folder. That worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Please, check if your Bolt target has a Info.plist in Identity as the image below, if not, click on the button with title Choose Info.plist File... and choose it.
[image]

Comment: I don't have bolt target in my project, it is in under pod project and identity is not showing like yours. It's looking like other normal pod target.

Comment: Hi Tapas, I believe that you open the .xcodeproj file you can open the .xcworkspace and you'll see the Pods project, open it and you'll see all the target.

Comment: No I open the right one. check it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN698.png

Comment: Try to delete the Pods folder and Podfile.lock and execute the pod install again. I hope that helps.

Comment: I am not very sure what exact solution solved my problem.. I tried yours and also some other tricks available on internet. Now it's working fine;

Comment: @TapasPal If you discover, share with us ;)

Comment: I had the same problem, then I quitted XCode and run it again, everything started working fine.

Comment: Another trick that might work is to **quit** iPhone Simulator and try again.

Answer (score 5):

Check your bundle identifier. If you create your project with bundle identifier like com.example.com and then you change your bundle identifier then it causes above error.I have same issue, then i check my bundle identifier which i was set during project setup & then i change it it causes above error.

Comment: It should be the bundle identifier has changed, restart the simulator should fix it.