# Xcode 11.3.1 Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I have React Native project which stops working after Xcode upgrade to version 11.3.1. The error is following

```
Could not install at this time.
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/dmytro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F0BD5650-04A4-4534-B3F6-56B74ED1B0C2/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.aRWRdh/extracted/Target.app/Frameworks/RCTVibration.framework; Extra info about plist: ACL=<not found
```

[image]

and details

```
Details

This app could not be installed at this time.
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Could not install at this time.
Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/dmytro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F0BD5650-04A4-4534-B3F6-56B74ED1B0C2/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.aRWRdh/extracted/Target.app/Frameworks/RCTVibration.framework; Extra info about plist: ACL=<not found> 
--
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/dmytro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F0BD5650-04A4-4534-B3F6-56B74ED1B0C2/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.aRWRdh/extracted/Target.app/Frameworks/RCTVibration.framework; Extra info about plist: ACL=<not found> 
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 35
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[MIBundle _validateWithError:]";
    LegacyErrorString = PackageInspectionFailed;
    SourceFileLine = 128;
}
--
```

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using CocoaPods v1.9+, if you can't remove `use_frameworks!` from `Podfile`, you can set:

```
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

> Now that Swift supports static linking, CocoaPods has expanded this
>   DSL to allow specifying the type of linkage preferred.

Source: https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.9.0-beta/

Comment: Are there any consequences to adding `:linkage => :static`?

Comment: Thanks mate, spent lot of time. finally this worked. But my doubt is also same.Are there consequences for this?

Comment: @Ravi You're welcome! I think no, because Cocoapods using this, will generate full frameworks with statically linked libraries and module map files.

Answer (score 6):

The solution for me was to remove `use_frameworks!` from `Podfile`.

Don't forget `pod install`, clear Derived Data and `Erase All Content And Settings` on your Simulator.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but in my case, I need to use use_frameworks! as mandatory, looking for a solution for almost 1 day. But still no clue

Comment: @JothiKannan it is not required to use `use_frameworks!` since cocoa pods 1.5, check http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.5.0/. Why do you need it?

Comment: I am using this https://pushy.me/docs/additional-platforms/react-native, push notification SDK which requires `use_frameworks!`

Comment: I haven't experience with it, my suggestion to try to update cocoapods to the latest version and try to use it without `use_frameworks!`

Comment: I tried it, I have cocopod 1.9.1 and tried without `use_frameworks!` and ended up with lot of errors

Answer (score 1):

I have found a detailed solution here with screenshots:

https://handyopinion.com/solution-failed-to-load-info-plist-from-bundle-at-path-in-xcode/

**Steps:**

**1.** remove use_frameworks! from Podfile

**2.** Run `pod install` command

**3.** Delete Content of Derived Data Folder. For that navigate to `File -> Workspace Settings` in xCode then navigate to the Derived data folder and remove its content.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `YourTarget` > `Build Settings` > `Packaging` > `Info.plist File` and check here the path to your `.plist` file.

Also it would be helpful to clear your `derived data` folder, and re-build project again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Info.plist settings is fine. The error points to the Pods library, so maybe the issue related to the Pods.

Comment: That may be because there are two Plist files. Delete one of them. Also, try to give the path for plist in the xcodeproj after restarting the Xcode, where you can give the path initially somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in Pod v1.11.2. I tried restarting the simulator, erasing content, restarting the machine, removed derived data from File->WorkSpace settings -> {derived data}

Nothing worked for me. Finally, the below magic steps helped,

1. In the pod file replace 'use_frameworks!' with 'use_frameworks! :linkage => :static'
2. Run 'pod install' // now you might get some other issue
3. Revert 'use_frameworks! :linkage => :static' changes i.e replace 'use_frameworks! :linkage => :static' with 'use_frameworks!'
4. Again run 'pod install'