# xcode simulator not loading - info.plist error - GoogleMapsFramework issue

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, frameworks

I've been having this issue for several days now.  I've successfully moved my code base to a new MacBook (M1), removed all CocoaPods & swapped them out for Swift packages.

All the code successfully compiles without issue now (Xcode 14.2 & 15) but right as the simulator loads up, I get this error message below.

I've tried clearing the cache on the simulator, restarting it, cleaning out derived data, and ensuring I don't have multiple plist files - not sure what else to try.

> Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.  Please try again later. Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path

[image: Simulator error message]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load Info.plist from bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327935/failed-to-load-info-plist-from-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

To close this out - I discovered that my info plist file was not included in the "Compile Sources" in the "Build Phases" under my Target.  Adding it in immediately solved this issue.

[image]